# How to Click on the button recaptcha using selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I need help,I try do click on the recaptcha with selenium on C#, But It not working, I can't found by Xpath the element

```
ChromeDriver driver;
driver.FindElement(By.Id("recaptcha-reload-button")).Click();
```

[it's the div but I don't have the xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBsGJ.png)
[I need do click on this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5mIE.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  And please post the (minimal amount of) code to reproduce your problem instead of screenshots.  You are attempting to programatically bypass reCaptcha?  Isn't it designed to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion on this, the idea behind reCaptcha is to prevent bot activities on the site. What ever you do with selenium is kind of bot activity. I would suggest to disable reCaptcha(if possible) in the lower environments and perform automation testing.